# How to secure DOM Parser

Tags: java, xml, security, xml-parsing

There was a security audit on my product and they have found a vulnerability and their recommendations are  An XML parser should be configured securely so that it does not allow document type definition (DTD) custom entities and external entities as part of an incoming XML document.

I was able to reslolve the issue for XML TransformerFactory, by implementing the following:

```
TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transFact.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
transFact.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
trans.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

But there is one code which they are pointing,  and I don't have any clue to resolve this.

```
public static DOMSource parse(String xmlPayload) throws ResourceException {
    try {
        DOMParser oracleDomParser = new DOMParser();
        oracleDomParser.parse(new StringReader(xmlPayload));
        Document doc = oracleDomParser.getDocument();
        return new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResourceException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I also getting same issue ,i getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD`. if you find any solution of that then please reply.